# SAS - column of Date9. conversion to MMDDYY10

Tags: date, sas

I have a DOB (date of birth) column that is already stored as a date9. format in the table. So, when I view the table, the DOB column has value such as 01Aug2013, 01Jul2001, etc. I would like to create a second column called DOB2, and have it as an informat of MMDDYYYY10, so that the date values informat is 08/01/2013, 07/01/2001, etc. when viewing the table.

I tried using the statement below, and the date format is correct, but the actual values are incorrect.
    DOB3 = input(put(DOB, 9.),mmddyy10.);

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `input` or `put` or whatnot; if it's a date formatted numeric, then:

```
dob2 = dob;
format dob2 mmddyy10.;
```

You can switch formats about however often you want, it's just a label sitting on top of the same underlying value.